# IdentityServer4 with Active Directory as an Identity Provider for SSO

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, identityserver4

Anyone know if the following is possible?

1. IdentityServer4 with Active Directory as an Identity Provider — How?
2. Extra claims and roles using IdentityServer4 that link back to an AD user — How?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to use AD as an identity provider in IdentityServer. Take a look at [mclark1129's IdentityServer4.Samples repo](https://github.com/mclark1129/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/AzureAd_CustomStateDataFormat) for an example. You can see the claims being generated in the AccountController.

While this example uses Azure AD, it is using it as a generic OpenIdConnect provider. Provided you are using a version of AD and Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) which support OpenIdConnect, you can [configure it is an upstream OpenIDConnect identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-openid-connect-with-ad-fs-2016).